# Problem with badge section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've noticed a strange behaviour with badge section at the bottom. Here's the picture of it. Some css file needs to be fixed. I've encountered this few minutes ago.

It happens on Wordpress stack exchange site.

Chrome browser, Windows 8 OS

Chrome browser, Debian 8 OS

[image]

Comment: Happens with Firefox 44.0.2 too. Taking a quick look at the CSS, there are several possible solutions, the most plausible seems to be reducing the search inputs width.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a senior product designer here at Stack Overflow. Thanks for reporting the issue. Another website reported a similar issue a couple weeks ago and I pushed a fix for this that appears to have corrected this issue as well. Huzzah!

The issue was related to the width of the search bar being too wide.